# Passing arguments to a function within a JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js

When composing objects with functions, what's the proper way to pass parameters *within* the composition object?

For example:

```
// functions
const sayHi = () => {
    console.log('Hi!');
};

const greetPerson = (name) => {
    console.log(`Hello there, ${name}!`);
};

// "composition" objects, referring to the functions above
const hi = {
    'id': 1,
    'speak': sayHi
};

const greetWorld = {
    'id': 2,
    'speak': greetPerson('World')  // how do I go about passing the function a parameter here?
};

const greetMars = {
    'id': 3,
    'speak': greetPerson('Mars')
};

// register and run each
const salutations = [hi, greetWorld, greetMars];

for (let salutation of salutations) {
    salutation.speak();
}
```

The output when I run this is:

```
$ node sayHi.js
Hello there, World!
Hello there, Mars!
Hi!
/Users/rotarydial/sayHi.js:21
    salutation.speak();

TypeError: salutation.speak is not a function
```

How do I handle this properly so I can pass `greetPerson()` a parameter in the `greet` object?

Comment: Also, if my terminology in this question is poor, please correct. (e.g., if what I'm calling a "composition object" is commonly called something else, I'd like to know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code, `greetPerson('World'), greetPerson('Mars')` were getting executed at the time of object creation only.

```
const greetWorld = {
    'id': 2,
    'speak': greetPerson('World')
};
```

was getting evaluate to below after execution

```
const greetWorld = {
     'id': 2,
     'speak': undefined // as it was getting execute immediately, and function by default returns undefined if nothing explicitly returned from it.
};
```

Fix -

```js
// functions
const sayHi = () => {
    console.log('Hi!');
};

const greetPerson = (name) => {
    console.log(`Hello there, ${name}!`);
};

// "composition" objects, referring to the functions above
const hi = {
    'id': 1,
    'speak': sayHi
};

const greetWorld = {
    'id': 2,
    'speak': () => greetPerson('World') // how do I go about passing the function a parameter here?
};

const greetMars = {
    'id': 3,
    'speak': () => greetPerson('Mars')
};

// register and run each
const salutations = [hi, greetWorld, greetMars];

for (let salutation of salutations) {
    salutation.speak();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by declaring the function with parameter as an anonymous function, like this:

```
'speak': () => greetPerson('World')
```

Comment: I struggled to find this online anywhere, so I'm answering my own question in the hopes it'll help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you're looking for:

```
// functions
const sayHi = () => {
    console.log('Hi!');
};

const greetPerson = (name) => {
    console.log(`Hello there, ${name}!`);
};

// "composition" objects, referring to the functions above
const hi = {
    'id': 1,
    'speak': sayHi
};

const greet = {
    'id': 2,
    'speak': greetPerson // pass in a reference to the function for later use.
};

// register and run each
const salutations = [hi, greet];

for (let salutation of salutations) {
    salutation.speak("World!");
}
```

I suggest you read the MDN [Working with Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) page, particularly the section `Defining Methods`

Here's an example from that page:

```
objectName.methodname = functionName;

var myObj = {
  myMethod: function(params) {
    // ...do something
  }

  // OR THIS WORKS TOO

  myOtherMethod(params) {
    // ...do something else
  }
};
```

Comment: In my real-world case, I specifically don't want the iterator to pass the parameter. I want to set it in the "composition" object.

Comment: Have you looked up [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) and [setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set)?